# ASP.Net, Crystal Reports not working when deployed. Event viewer Event ID 4353

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm have a VS 2011 web application. Reports worked fine in development enviornment, but when hosted in the server all I got is a blank page with no error or any thing. When looked at the event viewer I found this error:

"The description for Event ID ( 4353 ) in Source ( Crystal Reports ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: The keycode assembly, BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder.dll, cannot be loaded."

And still wasn't able to solve it. I'm running a VS 2010 Web based application hosted on a Windows Server 2003 Machine.

In the QA Server I got the same problem and was able to fix the problem by copying the asp_Client in InetPub to the Virtual directory root pointed.

But in the Production environment we don't have a Virtual Directory and directly hosted under wwwRoot. And got the same problem, still unable to solve it. Would appreciate if any one can help me on this. I have given permissions to SapBusinessObjects directory as mentioned above,but still not working.

Thanks in advance.
Thanushka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked form me after copping the asp_client folder of www_root to the application folder of the app's deployed in virtual directory. Basically crystal reports install the js files to the root. Not the virtual paths. So by copying the folder your making available the js files to the app's in the virtual path as well.

Hope this'll work for others as well.

Good luck.