# Crystal report wont display in browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, crystal-reports

using crystal reports 13 with VS 2010. everything works fine on the development machine. 
once deployed the reports wont show in the browser. on the web server (windows 2008, IIS7) i have installed crystal report run time.... feel like i am missing something else... has anybody experienced the same issue..

another issue i did notice was on the development machine , the crystal reports were sensitive to the browser that it was run on... on the latest browsers no problem at all, but in IE 7 or 8, only quarter  of the reports would appear.... how can one over come this...

Rgrds
Adr17

Comment: You say "the reports won't show", but does anything happen at all when you run the report on the web server?  In other words, does the page come up OK but blank?  Or is there an error?  etc..

Comment: yes the page does work, but where the report is suppose to appear, it just empty, nothing....

Comment: Did the report definitely deploy to the web server?  I had a problem recently where the report file properties (in Visual Studio) were set to not copy the file to the server.  I suppose you'd probably get an error but just brainstorming here...

Comment: yes they have been Ken,checked the IIS error logs, getting an ID 4353  Crystal report error...

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071248/asp-net-crystal-reports-not-working-when-deployed-event-viewer-event-id-4353) and this [SAP Thread](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1761451) both agree that it could be fixed by copying your aspnet_client folder to the root of your project.  I did have to do that with one of my projects, so maybe it'll help you?

Comment: i did see that post, but didn't make sense to me because i don't see an aspnet_client folder

Comment: ok did some research, ran the command aspnet_regiis -c. after you republish the project it does create an aspnet_client folder. copied it into my web server... still no luck. am i doing anything wrong??

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/vscrystalreports/thread/ef56f72b-7ede-47d8-ba9e-9e63b9ac0203 , the answer to my question.

Comment: @AJ17 - when you're allowed to do so, move the link to an answer, and accept it.  This could help some other folks I'm sure.

Comment: @ken - yep will do, i did more research into  the solution that you had suggested and it works to(thanks for taking time in helping me out). when i had tried it before i copied the wrong aspnet_client folder. we have to copy the aspnet_client folder in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client (this will be in your web server ) and paste it in the folder where your website will reside (c:websitesTohost/websiteA). that it....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the solution is to copy the folder aspnet_Client into your web application (you will find the folder in wwwroot)

Answer (score 0):

```
Crystal Report TroubleShooting
1.  Bob is undefined, copy file under IIS default folder's crystal report file to web site's place
2.  Invalid Index => alias name not same with stored procedure name
3.  Remember to verify database
4.  try to exec stored procedure in management studio and make sure select explicit field name instead of *
5.  try to preview crystal report
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my reports where a virtual directory (IIS7) and Crystal Reports has a bug where it looks for the files in the aspnet_client folder in the root of the website and not in the virtual directory.  So I had to copy the aspnet_client folder to the root.